# Turning Gridview Headers to 90 degree angle

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

net with vb.net web pages (Not WPF )

I have a grid view and I need to display the grid view  headers in 90 degree angle. I want the header to look like below picture.

Can some one suggest me how can I do that?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried that did not work? Do you have any relevant code you could share with us?

Comment: well, try to type in google search, for example, *rotate text css* and see results...

Comment: I tried rotate but it did not work.       .rotate {
   -ms-transform: rotate(18deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(18deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(18deg);
}

      th.rotate {
   transform: 
    /* Magic Numbers */
    translate(25px, 51px)
    /* 45 is really 360 - 45 */
    rotate(315deg);
  width: 30px;
}

Comment: .verticaltext
        {
          
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            filter: flipv fliph;
        } I was able to achieve it with below css

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve that by using below css

.verticaltext
        {
            /*writing-mode: tb-rl;*/
            writing-mode: vertical-rl;
            filter: flipv fliph;
        }